# Parse Only one Value from json array which is nested inside another json array into android

Tags: android, arrays, json, nested

Good day guys.Im Working on a company and my college reposing me some json array but as per requirements the json array must be the next

```
...some array code here
//Here i give the main array name as data but i don't need to post that part

       Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id_] => 30340428
                [number] => 10001
                [mobile] =>> 10001
                [mobile] =0712200096
                [name] => 0
                [sms_body] => Hello World
                [date] => 2014-10-06 17:09:52
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id_] => 5782398452
                [number] => 3246436
                [mobile] => 8727266262
                [name] => mynam
                [sms_body] => Yollalahihu
                [date] => 2014-10-06 17:09:52
            )

    )
```

As you can see there is an two arrays which each of them having same key names but different values per requirements of my android program.
And here is my code to parse this json array into android

```
  JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(theresultstring);
               JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("data");//this is the main array header key name which i didn't posted in array by this I'm able to get into my array

               for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                String number = jsonChildNode.optString("id");
                String name = jsonChildNode.optString("number");
                String resume = jsonChildNode.optString("mobile");
                String address = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
```

Everything works except one thing.I searched the whole interned but no solution. I want to parse for example the value of second array only!!!!with my above code when i parse lets say the value of name i get the both of other the `"0"` and the `"mynam"`
but at the point i only want to fetch the one value lets say the first name value not the second arrays name value how can i do it???i just cane understand logic of it,i tried to loop through json array i tried to use while statement i tried almost everything nothing nothgin i just need to fetch one value from these two arrays and not get the both values for `"name"` how to do it having such json array code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple solution of what you are asking (at least what I understand).

If you want to parse only first array then do this

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(theresultstring);
JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("data");//this is the main array header key name which i didn't posted in array by this I'm able to get into my array
JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(0);            
String number = jsonChildNode.optString("id");
String name = jsonChildNode.optString("number");
String resume = jsonChildNode.optString("mobile");
String address = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
```

If you want to parse only second array then do this

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(theresultstring);
JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("data");//this is the main array header key name which i didn't posted in array by this I'm able to get into my array
JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(1); 
...rest of the code...
```

If your json array length is not fixed (more of less than 2) and you want only first array then again first solution would work. But if you want the last array then do this

```
 JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(theresultstring);
JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("data");//this is the main array header key name which i didn't posted in array by this I'm able to get into my array
JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(jsonMainNode.length() - 1); 
...rest of the code...
```

Also a null check would be a nice thing to add here.